# How can I make byobu handle Ctrl+B?

Tags: byobu

I'm used to tmux, so I want Byobu to use Ctrl+B as the escape sequence. I hit F9, *Change escape sequence*, and `B`.

But when I hit Ctrl+B on the shell, it moves one character back instead of letting byobu/tmux handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I typically don't use the `F9` menu stuff, so this is relatively new to me. However, when I did that and pressed `B` (no `ctrl` since that is assumed/forced), it immediately worked correctly (without a restart). I'm not certain why it would not work with your configuration.

Since `byobu` is really keeping its own store of configuration items and forcing `screen`/`tmux` to use its versions, you can find *what* to change by looking in `~/.byobu/`, and *how* to change it by reading the respective man/help pages.

You can edit `byobu`'s config files behind the scenes (not always a good idea, but should be acceptable here). Since `byobu` uses either `screen` or `tmux` (based on what is installed), the answer can reside in either `~/.byobu/keybindings` (for screen) or `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux`.

I played around with using both `screen` and `tmux` ... choose one (defaults to `tmux` if installed, I think) and go with it.

## First things first

Check to make sure that `echo $HOME` prints what you expect (not a blank line). If there is not a directory called `.byobu` within that home directory, then either the `byobu` installation is dorked or you don't have the correct permissions set in your home directory; try `mkdir "${HOME}/.byobu"`, and if it doesn't work than that could be part of your problem.

## `screen`

From `man screen`

> ...
>
> ```
>  escape xy
>
>  Set  the  command  character  to  x and the character generating a literal command
>  character (by triggering the "meta" command) to y  (similar  to  the  -e  option).
>  Each  argument  is either a single character, a two-character sequence of the form
>  "^x" (meaning "C-x"), a backslash followed by  an  octal  number  (specifying  the
>  ASCII  code of the character), or a backslash followed by a second character, such
>  as "\^" or "\\".  The default is "^Aa".
> ```
>
> ...

The first line of `~/.byobu/keybindings` should have `byobu`'s *source* command, so don't change it. After it, ***add*** the following:

```
escape "^Bb"
register x "^B"
bindkey "^B"
```

(This is taken verbatim from what `byobu` did to my install. Historically -- since I use `screen`/`tmux` without `byobu` much of the time -- I actually just set:

```
escape "^Bb"
defescape "^Bb"
```

This may not be the best way, and it has some historical kludgeness to it, but it works for me.)

## `tmux`

Similarly, from `man tmux`:

> ```
>        prefix key
>                Set the key accepted as a prefix key.
>
>        prefix2 key
>                Set a secondary key accepted as a prefix key.
> ```

My `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` doesn't have a *source* command, so my file only contained the following:

```
unbind-key -n C-b
set -g prefix ^B
set -g prefix2 ^B
bind b send-prefix
```

## If This Doesn't Work

Knowing your OS and software versions will be useful. I tested this on ubuntu-13.10 with byobu-5.60-0ubuntu1, screen-4.0.3-14ubuntu10, and tmux-1.8-4.

Comment: Thanks, I had to manually edit `keybindings.tmux` like you suggested, restart byobu and now it works. For some reason, the F9 menu had modified `keybindings` instead.